# Trying to read a 93lc46b chip using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom

I am trying to read a 93lc46b EEPROM chip using Arduino. I am reusing the code from http://owlsan.blogspot.de/2012/10/accessing-93c4693c46n-serial-eeprom.html, except I have modified it for 93lc46b chip, plus I am using Arduino Uno and not Arduino Mega. The problem I am facing is, I get different set of bytes every time I try to read 93lc46b EEPROM chip. I doubt this might be some garbage data. Can you please explain me what and where exactly I am doing something wrong. The modified code snippet is as follows:

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define CLEAN 0b00000000

#define DDR93LC46B  _SFR_IO8(0x04)
#define PORT93LC46B _SFR_IO8(0x05)
#define PIN93LC46B  _SFR_IO8(0x03)

#define SK 13 
#define DO 12 
#define DI 11 
#define CS 10 

#define READ 0x02 

#define SET_CS PORT93LC46B |= (1 << CS)
#define CLR_CS PORT93LC46B &= ~(1 << CS)

#define SET_SK {PORT93LC46B |= (1 << SK); _delay_us(0.01);}
#define CLR_SK PORT93LC46B &= ~(1 << SK)

#define SET_DI PORT93LC46B |= (1 << DI)
#define CLR_DI PORT93LC46B &= ~(1 << DI)

class SPI_93LC46B {
  private:
    uint8_t Transfer(uint8_t data) {
      SPDR = data;
      while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF))); // Wait for SPI interrupt flag
      return SPDR;                  // Return byte gathered from SPI data register
    }
    void Opcode(uint8_t opcode, uint8_t address) {
      SET_CS;
      SPCR &= ~(1 << SPE);               // SPI disable
     _delay_us(1);
      CLR_SK;
      SET_DI;                            // Send start bit
      SET_SK;
      CLR_SK;
      SPCR |= (1 << SPE);         // SPI enable
      Transfer((opcode << 6) | address); // Transmit byte
    }
  public:
    SPI_93LC46B() {
      SPCR =    CLEAN        // Set SPI control register
         & ~(1 << SPIE)  // SPI interrupt disable
         |  (1 << SPE)   // SPI enable
         & ~(1 << DORD)  // MSB first
         |  (1 << MSTR)  // SPI master device
         & ~(1 << CPOL)  // SPI
         & ~(1 << CPHA)  //  mode 0
         |  (1 << SPR1)  // XX/64 MHz
         & ~(1 << SPR0); //  speed
      SPSR =    CLEAN         // Init SPI status register
         & ~(1 << SPI2X); // SPI double speed
      DDR93LC46B =    CLEAN      // Set up inputs/outputs
             |  (1 << SK)  // Serial clock output
             |  (1 << DI)  // Data input (MOSI) output
             |  (1 << CS)  // Chip select output
             & ~(1 << DO); // Data output (MISO) input
      PORT93LC46B |= (1 << DO); // Data output (MISO) high
      CLR_DI;
      CLR_CS;    
      CLR_SK;
     _delay_us(1);
    }
    ~SPI_93LC46B() {
      //
    }
    uint16_t Read(uint8_t address) {
      uint16_t data = 0;
      Opcode(READ, address);              
      CLR_DI;
      SET_SK;                             
      CLR_SK;
      SPCR |=  (1 << CPHA);       
      data = Transfer(0);
      data = (data << 8) | (Transfer(0));
     _delay_us(1);
      CLR_CS;
      CLR_DI;
      SPCR &= ~(1 << CPHA);   
      return data;
   }
};

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  _delay_ms(100);
  Serial.println("EEPROM writing/reading");
}

void loop(void) {
  Serial.println("new round");
  SPI_93LC46B _93LC46B;
  int i;
  uint16_t data;
  for(i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    data = _93LC46B.Read(i);
    _delay_ms(50);
    Serial.print(data, HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
    if((i + 1) % 8 == 0)
      Serial.println();
  }
  _delay_ms(10000);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is over complicated and has a lot of errors. Let us start with the obvious. Look closely at this section. Do you see the error(s)?

```
#define SK 13 
#define DO 12 
#define DI 11 
#define CS 10 

#define READ 0x02 

#define SET_CS PORT93LC46B |= (1 << CS)
#define CLR_CS PORT93LC46B &= ~(1 << CS)

#define SET_SK {PORT93LC46B |= (1 << SK); _delay_us(0.01);}
#define CLR_SK PORT93LC46B &= ~(1 << SK)

#define SET_DI PORT93LC46B |= (1 << DI)
#define CLR_DI PORT93LC46B &= ~(1 << DI)
```

The symbols SK, D0, DI, CS seem to be pin numbers but look how they are used in the SET_XX and CLR_XX macros. That is very wrong. They should be the bit numbers in the PORT register instead.

There is more. How about this?

```
_delay_us(0.01);
```

What is the intention? _delay_ns(10)??? In any case yet another error.

Cheers!